# Adding fields to webpages_Membership SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, simplemembership

Is it possible to add fields/columns to `webpages_Membership`?

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
public Membership()
{
    Roles = new List<Role>();
    OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
}

[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
[StringLength(128)]
public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
[Required, StringLength(128)]
public string Password { get; set; }
public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
[Required, StringLength(128)]
public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
[StringLength(128)]
public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add LogonCount as a field/column, but this table gets filled automatically by the `membership provider` upon creating a `CreateUserAndAccount()`.

I don't seem to have any influence on giving the LogonCount a value at `CreateUserAndAccount()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to add information relevant to a given userId is in the `UserProfile` table, not the `webpages_Membership` table. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631) and [Jon Galloway's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) on "*SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates*" for more info about how SimpleMembership ties together with `UserProfile`.

> I don't seem to have any influence on giving the LogonCount a value ...

You then access the `UserProfile` table and information through your database context, not through the membership provider, which is really there to give you access to a core set of features only.

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
  UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles
    .First(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
  user.LogonCount = 1;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok, so webpages_Membership is off limits. got it.

Comment: You probably could use it, but you don't want to as the membership provider cares about it's schema just as much as you do

Comment: @Yustme. Added a ref in the answer to [my SO answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631) for more info about how SimpleMembership ties together with `UserProfile`, which might help as well.

Comment: Andy, I'm very jealous about the answer he got from you! :o But thanks!