# How do I use my own database with SimpleMembership and WebSecurity? What is MVC4 security all about?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider, simplemembership

I've read everything on this topic I could find, including MSDN articles and SO posts, but I'm still very lost and confused.

### Questions

Please answer the following (briefly, if possible):

1. What is **SimpleMembership/SimpleMembershipProvider** (*WebMatrix.WebData*) and what is it/are they responsible for?
2. What is **WebSecurity** (*WebMatrix.WebData*)?
3. What is the **Membership** (*System.Web.Security*) class?
4. Why does MVC4 create a **UserProfile** table and a **webpages_Membership** table? What are they for and what is the difference? What is the UserProfile class that MVC4 creates?
5. What is the **UsersContext** class?
6. How do all of these work together to make user authentication?

### My Situation

These questions then lead into the next problem:

Suppose I have an existing database with users (IDs, Usernames, passwords). I'm creating a new MVC4 application and using Forms Authentication. User passwords are stored in the database in an encrypted form (not bcrypt).

What do I have to do to make it work with MVC4?

Do I have to create a custom *MembershipProvider*?

### My Knowledge Thus Far

As far as I can understand, *WebSecurity* is a static class (Module) that interacts with a *MembershipProvider*. A MembershipProvider is a class that explains how particular functions work, such as *ValidateUser*, *CreateUser*, *ChangePassword*.

To solve my problem I assume I need to create a custom MembershipProvider and tell WebSecurity to use my new MembershipProvider.

### Bounty?

I have placed a bounty on this question and intend to award it to Andy Brown for an outstanding answer.

Comment: This is a fairly unpopular opinion but I suggest you stay away from the built in security models of .Net. They're confusing, inefficient and a poor attempt at allowing joe coder to create a secure website. In my opinion if you don't understand how the security works you shouldn't be touching it. Moreover once an attack vector has been discovered for any ASP.Net security setup every website that uses it is vulnerable. If you write your own at least you have the benefit of it's exploits not being documented all around the web. Learn how to create a secure website and use your own implementation.

Comment: Interesting, I'll certainly learn more about your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: At the current time, using SSL for logins and registration and SHAx hashing along with password salts will protect you from the most common concerns. Look into how to avoid session spoofing and you'll have as much security as you need for basic website memberships. If you're dealing with credit cards I recommend you do a lot more research.

Comment: @SpencerRuport. I am neither agreeing nor disagreeing, but to roll your own doesn't mean it will be secure either, and readers should consider their level of expertise and time before doing that. My answer has a couple of references to both sides of the open source security argument.

Comment: @Rowan. Your question is huge and made up of at least 9 questions. I suggest you read my answer for answers 1-6, ask a new question for "how do I use my existing table with SimpleMembership" and link to it from here. Nobody is going to read to the end of any answer to this question, so it doesn't create value for SO users.

Comment: @RowanFreeman. You mention _encrypted_ passwords in your database. I have added an edit about the difference between hashed and encrypted in an edit to my answer. In case you are not confident of the difference, and why it's important, you should think carefully before rolling your own security.

Comment: I would also add that if you're working with MVC4 and are going to end up doing a custom authentication, it may be worth you're time looking into Claims Based authentication. For a simple replacement of Forms Authentication. [Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/) has a [great post on this](http://brockallen.com/2013/01/26/replacing-forms-authentication-with-wifs-session-authentication-module-sam-to-enable-claims-aware-identity/).

Answer (score 189, accepted):

*See the summaries below each quote for a quick answer, and the paragraphs for detail. Also see the References section at the end for the authoritative sources.*

#### Summaries

> 1.What is SimpleMembership/SimpleMembershipProvider (WebMatrix.WebData) and what is it/are they responsible for?

SimpleMembership (a term that covers both the [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and [`SimpleRoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)) is responsible for providing a clean and quick way of implementing an 80 %-there plug and play authentication and authorisation framework with secure password storage, that anyone can use.

> 2.What is WebSecurity (WebMatrix.WebData)?

[`WebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547905%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is a helper class for common membership tasks that works alongside `Membership` and [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.webpages.oauth.oauthwebsecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Roles are still accessed separately through [`Roles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx).

> 3.What is the Membership (System.Web.Security) class?

[`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) is a static class from the original ASP.NET membership implementation that manages user settings and operations. Many user operations are still done here rather than repeating them in `WebSecurity`. They both use the same provider of your choice.

> 4.Why does MVC4 create a UserProfile table and a webpages_Membership table? What are they for and what is the difference? What is the UserProfile class that MVC4 creates?

The two tables perform different functions. The `webpages_Membership` schema is controlled by the framework and used for credentials, the `UserProfile` schema is controlled by us and used for any properties we want to store against a user.

> 5.What is the UsersContext class?

It is a [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (part of the [DbContext API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192989.aspx)) provided as a starting by the MVC Internet Application template. Its only job is to contain the `UserProfile` class so we can work with it (e.g. through `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`).

> 6.How do all of these work together to make user authentication?

This should now be evident from the summaries above and the detail below. Use: `WebSecurity` for common tasks; `UserProfile` for custom properties to store against a user, accessed through the `UsersContext` (in the Visual Studio "MVC Internet Application" template); `Membership` when `WebSecurity` or `OAuthWebSecurity` doesn't have the method; and `Roles` for roles. Use the VS template's controller to see examples of use.

**Edit**. In case anyone got this far

> Suppose I have an existing database ...

If you have an existing database, and your only reason for writing a custom membership provider is to deal with your legacy password storage method, then you could use a workaround. This will only work if you can move away from your old password storage to the SimpleMembership algorithm (which uses the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class). See the footnote for details.

If you can't move away, then yes you are going to have to create your own provider to use your specific password algorithm, which you can do [by deriving from `SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2012/11/15/customize-the-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0.aspx).

**NOTE: `SimpleMembershipProvider` will [HASH your passwords not ENCRYPT them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/1831275). If you don't know the difference and why that is important then think twice before doing your own provider with custom security**

---

### Detail

#### 1.What is SimpleMembership/SimpleMembershipProvider

To understand how it all fits together it helps to understand the history.

- ASP.NET in 2005 [introduced the ASP.NET Membership system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- This system used providers to abstract away implementation details from common interfaces used to manage accounts and roles etc.
- It also gave us a basic "user profile" capability (stored in a single column xml field which people therefore tended to avoid)
- SimpleMembership was released into the world in 2010 ish as a provider that plugs in to the ASP.NET membership system, but also allows for OAuth authentication, and property-per-column user profile storage (instead of the single column storage used in the original implementation).
- [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) implements [`ExtendedMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to extend the original provider implementation

It is Open Source [on codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) (mirrored [on github](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack)). As far as security goes you can therefore assess the code yourself, clone it, change it etc. You should take [your own view](http://www.zdnet.com/six-open-source-security-myths-debunked-and-eight-real-challenges-to-consider-7000014225/) on the [benefits and drawbacks](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/06/open-source_sof.html) of [open source security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software_security), and cook that up up with a pinch of [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here#In_computing). (*Personal view: I use it sometimes, I don't use it other times*)

`ExtendedMembershipProvider` in itself adds commands like `GeneratePasswordResetToken` to the old membership provider apis.

#### 2.What is WebSecurity (WebMatrix.WebData)?

[`WebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547905%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is simply a facade, or helper class, to provide simple access to `SimpleMembershipProvider` and make common tasks easy and accessible in one place. It is there both to help and because the extension of the original framework through `ExtendedMembershipProvider` means some of the original classes like `Membership` aren't enough now. Examples:

- [`WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.currentusername%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) - gets the name of the currently logged in user
- [`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Simultaneously create a user and set user profile properties (e.g. `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(userName, pw, new { Email = model.Email });`
- [`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) - Quickly setup a new/existing database for use with membership, choose your user id column and user natural key identifier etc.
- `ResetPassword` to reset a user password, `GeneratePasswordResetToken` and many more

These methods generally defer *to the provider you are using*, they don't just depend on SimpleMembership, and they tie together objects like your provider and `Membership` to provide a common point to do membership functions.

Note there is also [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.webpages.oauth.oauthwebsecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which is the equivalent of `WebSecurity` for OAuth authentication.

#### 3.What is the Membership (System.Web.Security) class?

`Membership` is from the original implementation; it manages user settings and performs user-related operations using the basic `MembershipProvider` implementation which `ExtendedMembershipProvider` now extends. It is a static class, so is available anywhere you declare the namespace, and is therefore an easy way to, for example, retrieve the current user: `Membership.GetUser`

There is confusion caused by the fact that `WebSecurity` does some things and not others, and `Membership` does some things and not others. If you view `WebSecurity` as a toolkit for higher level operations, and `Membership` as a toolkit to do things to a user, you'll be ok; they work together on your provider.

#### 4.Why does MVC4 create a UserProfile table and a webpages_Membership table? What are they for and what is the difference? What is the UserProfile class that MVC4 creates?

- `webpages_Membership` is a table with a fixed schema that we leave alone, and allows the provider to do the basic account operations, mainly storing credentials.
- `UserProfile` is a table that we customise to store information against a user account, and have that made available in a strongly typed format through the `UserProfile` class.
- There is an extra table called `webpages_OAuthMembership` which does the same job as `webpages_Membership`, but for OAuth login providers that you want to integrate with.

The magic of this setup is that a single user can have a membership login on your own site, and any number of OAuth logins with different providers like google, facebook, and they all share a common profile stored in `UserProfile`

Generally if a table starts with `webpages_`, it means there is an API to access it. The `UserProfile` table is represented by the `UserProfile` class in your `UsersContext` (if you use the default MVC Internet Application template). Therefore we access this through the usual methods we would use with any class contained in a `DbContext`.

`UserProfile` is very code-first friendly: you can add columns (like the user's `Email` address), and then set up a migration to include that column in your database on your next release (if you like using migrations). In fact, the `UserProfile` table does not have to be called that - you can change that using the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` call, `[Table("UserProfile")] public class UserProfile`, and your own migrations.

#### 5.What is the UsersContext class?

This is from the MVC Internet Application template provided in Visual Studio New Project. The first thing I do is make sure that it shares a common connection string with my own database context (assuming the membership tables are in the same database). You can change this and decouple them later if you want.

You don't need to have it separate to your own context - that is only necessary if you want to store membership information in a different database now or in the future If you get rid of it you can just change references to `UsersContext` to your own context, adjusting `Database.SetInitializer`.

**References:**

[Using SimpleMembership With ASP.NET WebPages - Matthew Osborn](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages)
- This is the original reference about SimpleMembership and what it is, why it is, and what it does:

[MSDN - Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- Membership is still at the core of SimpleMembership, so it helps to understand a bit about it.

- [codeplex source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) (mirrored [on github](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack)).
- [`WebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547905%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.webpages.oauth.oauthwebsecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [`ExtendedMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [`SimpleRoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx)
- [`Roles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx)
- [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and the [DbContext API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192989.aspx)

---

**EDIT** Footnote: the detail for doing a rolling password upgrade

- Add a property to `UserProfile` which stores what password version the account is on (e.g. 1 for legacy, 2 for SimpleMembership)
- In the "Login" Action, write code so that:

  - If they are on your SimpleMembership password version, you do a normal login
  - If they are on the legacy password version, you:

    - check it using your old method
    - if it is correct you reset it using `ResetPassword` then `ChangePassword` to use the SimpleMembership version, this will update the field to the new password version
    - and finally update the Password version on the `UserProfile`
- Update any other AccountsController methods that use password in a similar way.
- Live with the hacky workaround and coupling to the `webpages_Membership` table we aren't meant to touch as you didnt have to write a new custom provider.

It is possible to make all this transactional with [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). The only nasty thing going on is the extra code in the controller, and the coupling to `webpages_Membership`.

Comment: @andy-brown Great answer. The third party links are showing their age (in the form of dead links.) Since those reference links are a bit out of date now and there was not enough space to post my addendum as a reply with those details I made an separate answer to contain those updates... Who knew a decade later someone would still need this info. but here I am. Please use any of this as you see fit to enhance this or just live along side your complete answer. I am not out of this 'hole' yet. I am treating it as a living document until my update of the system is complete.