# how can i get userid and username after login mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I created membership tables through codefirst.After login how can i get userid and username.i saw some links

`var userid=WebSecurity.CurrentUserId //it returns value -1`

```
var username=WebSecurity.CurrentUserName //it returns null
var uid=WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name) //it returns also -1
```

Comment: If you are using forms authentication, make sure formauthentication cookie is created.

Comment: Narendra, Are you using SimpleMembership, or did you create your own tables for webpages_Membership using code first? Those lines of code should work fine, especially `var username=WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` if you are using SimpleMembership

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SimpleMembership, or did you create your own tables for webpages_Membership using code first? If you use [SimpleMembership](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages) and get it to create your tables then `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` will work just fine and `var username=WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` will work once your user is logged in. Therefore it sounds like either

- The user is not logged in
- You are not using a membership provider
- The membership provider is not configured correctly

In fact, `WebSecurity` will work with other providers as well, the link that I posted above has more information on it.

Other than that, I would read the references for using SimpleMembership that I have posted in [this answer to "How do I use my own database with SimpleMembership and WebSecurity? What is MVC4 security all about?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631). There are a lot of potential problems that you have, and without a lot more information we aren't going to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I added [initializesimplemembershipprovider] attribute above in my controller.i created my own webpages_membership.thanks for reply.i will see your links.

Comment: @narendra. Don't create `webpages_membership` yourself (just delete that) as `WebSecurity` will do that for you. If you ask a new question "How do I use Simplemembership with my own code first DbContext" I will post a walkthrough answer in there to get you started. Link to it from a comment here once you have posted it.