# Is it worth to move to SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I have a project that is not released yet I will not be soon but I moved it from mvc3 to mvc4 a few days ago and while reading I saw this new security provider `SimpleMembership`.
The way I implement security now is by using `MembershipProvider` and `FormsAuthentication`:

- I have implemented ICustomPrincipal
- I have implemented CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
- I have implemented IPrincipal

To register user I use:

```
 MembershipCreateStatus status;
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
            Membership.CreateUser(model.User.Email.Trim(), model.Password.Trim(), model.User.Email.Trim(), null, null, true, g, out status);

            if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
...
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                             1,
                             tUser.Email,
                             DateTime.Now,
                             DateTime.Now.AddDays(60),
                             true,
                             userData);

                    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
...
```

But as I saw SimpleMembership looks much cleaner and I want to move project to it
but I have some questions about it:

**1)** I use stored procedures for all database actions I don't use EF at all. If I use SimpleMembership is it possible to use it without EF?

**2)** Do I need to build custom SimpleMembership for real world application?

**3)** I saw that it seeds database Create tables. I have my tables `Users, Profiles, Roles and UsersInRoles` can I apply it to my custom schema?

**4)** If I want to call `WebSecurity.CreateAccount(...)` and I want to call some my custom method from domain project that is responsible to call stored procedure that create user do I have to make it custom and if I have to do that is there some resource that explain how to make it custom for users and roles?

Comment: All I have to say is "If it aint broke, don't fix it."

Comment: So this new SimpleMembership is not superior over FormsAuthentication?

Comment: I can't say that for sure, I'm just saying that the risk level of putting it in at this point in your project is high. The current solution works, I'd recommend leaving it alone.

Comment: I think it is. More customizable and supports OAuth. OAuth can be very useful if you want to honor Facebook and Google logins. That said, @neoistheone s point is equally valid. If it aint broke...

Comment: The major difference between membership provider and simple membership is that with membership provider you use the schema that Microsoft gives you and in the simple membership case you can change the schema to support any additional fields that are needed as well as oauth support for example. Entity framework supports stored procedures

Comment: I made a mistake, I though that if I use simple membership I can't use forms Authentication. But when I made one test application I see that this two should work together. Please make your comment as answer so I can give you bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand SimpleMembership and how it has evolved from, and depends on, the previous Membership implementation, I recommmend reading the original reference "[Using SimpleMembership With ASP.NET WebPages (Matthew Osborn)](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages)", and my more detailed answer to "[What is MVC4 security all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631)" to understand it better. To summarise those references:

- SimpleMembership

  - is a term that covers both the `SimpleMembershipProvider` and the `SimpleRoleProvider`
  - is a storage and functionality provider that is used with Forms Authentication
  - works within ASP.NET Forms and ASP.NET MVC websites, and can also be used within ASP.NET Web API and SignalR, to provide a unified authentication and authorisation model
- `SimpleMembershipProvider`

  - adds new features to the original MembershipProvider through the `ExtendedMembershipProvider` abstract base class, such as integration with OAuth providers out of the box
  - creates 4 default tables which you don't/shouldn't interact with (`webpages_Membership`, `webpages_OAuthMembership`, `webpages_Roles`, `webpages_UsersInRoles`) and one (`UserProfile`) which is yours to structure as you wish
  - works with the `WebSecurity` helper class to add new functionality
  - Moves from the "user profile" stored in a single xml field in the original Membership, to a more manageable property-per-column in the new `UserProfile` table (which is fully customisable using EF)

To answer your specific questions:

> 1) I use stored procedures for all database actions I don't use EF at all. If I use SimpleMembership is it possible to use it without EF?

You would not generally interact directly with the tables prefixed with `webpages_` as there are API level functions in `Membership`, `WebSecurity` etc. to do all the business functions you require. However there is nothing to stop you interacting with `UserProfile` through stored procedures, and if you didn't want to take advantage of the APIs, you could even interact with the `webpages_` tables through sprocs as well (but you would just be duplicating all the benefits of SimpleMembership if you did).

> 2) Do I need to build custom SimpleMembership for real world application?

That very much depends on what you want to do, but as yet I have not had to do this for any real world applications. I have built on and added to the existing APIs, but not replaced them.

> 3) I saw that it seeds database Create tables. I have my tables Users, Profiles, Roles and UsersInRoles can I apply it to my custom schema?

If you were migrating to SimpleMembership you would have to port the data in these to the tables `webpages_Membership`, `webpages_OAuthMembership`, `webpages_Roles`, `webpages_UsersInRoles` and `UserProfile`. However, note that `UserProfile` can be called anything you want, you don't have to call it `UserProfile`.

> 4) If I want to call WebSecurity.CreateAccount(...) and I want to call some my custom method from domain project that is responsible to call stored procedure that create user do I have to make it custom and if I have to do that is there some resource that explain how to make it custom for users and roles?

Its a little hard to understand your requirement, however `WebSecurity.CreateAccount` does the following:

- Creates a record in `webpages_Membership` and
- optionally adds properties to `UserProfile` if you use `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`

If you wanted to do other actions across your database you would then need to call that after your call to `WebSecurity.CreateAccount`. You can make this transactional by using `TransactionScope`

If however you wanted to wrap this all in a single call to `WebSecurity.CreateAccount` and make it call your own domain methods and stored procedures you will have to create your own provider by inheriting from `SimpleMembershipProvider` (or from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`). When `WebSecurity.CreateAccount` then calls `ExtendedMembershipProvider.CreateAccount` it will defer to your custom logic

---

**Summary**

So would I migrate? The benefits of SimpleMembership are meant to be:

- UserProfile: property-per-column storage of user data that plays well with EF or any other db development method
- Integration with OAuth, allowing you to use Google, Facebook etc. authentication with very little effort
- High level business function APIs in the form of `WebSecurity`, and continued support of existing features with `Membership`
- Continued support for Roles that works with the [`Authorize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute
- Integration with EF so that you can use UserProfile along with your own tables
- Integration with standard Forms Authentication for ASP.NET Forms and MVC, and also with SignalR and Web API.

If those help you out, then migrate, otherwise spend your dev time on new features for your application.

If you do decide to migrate, then "[Migrating Legacy Apps to the New SimpleMembership Provider (Paul Brown)"](http://pretzelsteelersfan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/migrating-legacy-apps-to-new.html) is useful, which is summarised as:

- Modify `UserProfile` to have a field per property for your old user profile properties that were stored in xml
- Migrate your data from the `aspnet_` tables to the `webpages_` tables
- The first time each user logs in again, update their stored password to use the new hash model instead of the old `Membership` one (see [the footnote to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631) for how to do this)

Answer (score 0):

@Andy Brown makes a lot of good points.  I would note to anyone who lands on this that Simplemembership is basically dead and was short lived with ASP.Net Identity coming out shortly after it and is what is used in all new projects.   Such a short lived membership product.