# SimpleMembership default tables (membership) relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I am building a new **asp mvc 4** project. And I have added in `Application_Start()`

```
 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                "DefaultConnection", 
                "UserProfile", 
                "UserId", 
                "UserName", 
                true);
```

And when I have started the application it created me default tables like on diagram.
I have extended `UserProfile` to fit my needs.
On the diagram you can see that `webpages_OAuthMembership & webpages_Membership` tables are not in realtionship with any table.
Should I bind them to the `UserProfile` table by `UserId` as a **FK** or there is some reason to leave it like this?
I work with `SimpleMembership` for the first time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is up to you, but I would not recommend it in my opinion.

The main considerations are:

- All that the FKs will do is enforce referential integrity (they [will not impact performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507179/does-foreign-key-improve-query-performance) as much as carefully managing your indexes).
- As far as I am aware, there are no scenarios within SimpleMembership that will break if you use referential integrity.
- But as SimpleMembership creates the tables without the FKs, that is the way it has been tested to work; creating the FKs may therefore break some operations (however unlikely that is).

Therefore I don't create the FKs. I use the [SimpleMembership, WebSecurity, Membership, Roles etc. classes to do all membership operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704065/how-do-i-use-my-own-database-with-simplemembership-and-websecurity-what-is-mvc4/16734651#16734651), meaning I never need to access the tables directly. This also means that if there are edge cases where the referential integrity would break the SimpleMembership provider, I am not at risk of coming across them.